# how to make a UITableView return to the top at xcode?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ios4, iphone-4

I have a tableView that have at least 30 data. and then at the navigatorController i have a button that will change the view to another view. but if i want to back to my tableView i want to make the tableView return to the top? there are any code to make it work?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`UITableView` is a `UIScrollView` subclass so you can use its `setContentOffset:animated:` method to scroll to the top. You can do something like this in the `viewWillAppear:` method -

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
```